# How to stop ScheduledExecutorService after a certain number of starts or when a certain value returns?

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

I use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to execute 2 tasks at a fixed rate `scheduleAtFixedRate`. Both of these tasks return a value. How to stop execution of a task after a certain number of starts or when a certain value returns? Or maybe there are more suitable tools for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Once you submit task to ScheduledExecutorService, if task complete it's jobs then the task/thread automatically stop by the
   JVM.
2. If task takes to long to respond or you want stop in middle of execution, you can interrupt task/thread using
   future.cancel(true).
3. At the end you should shutdown ScheduledExecutorService by calling shutdown method on it.

Hope below code help you,

```
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);//pool size
    Callable<String> task = () -> {
        return "task1 completed";
    };
    String taskResponse = null;
    Future<String> future = service.submit(task);
    // Application thread wait for task to complete.
    while (!future.isDone()){
        // wait specific time or you can interrupt thread/task as below
        //future.cancel(true), it will interrupt task/thread.
    }
    if(future.isDone()){
        taskResponse = future.get();
    }
    // at end call Executor service shutdown
    service.shutdown();// you can do the same at finally block also.
```